# Docker Compose - XDebug - VScode Debugging setup

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, xdebug

I have a problem in debugging PHP with VSCode.

Dockerfile EXPOSE port **80**

The page I want to debug is really simple:

**home.php**

```
<?php

$name = 'AAA';
echo $name; <--- here is the breakpoint
```

**php.ini**

```
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 80
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

**launch.json** (XDebug configuration)

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9000
    }
  ]
}
```

Debug console doesn't show any error, but it's not stopped at breakpoint once I load the home-page.

Comment: *"Dockerfile EXPOSE port 80"* So what? Xdebug does not care about website port, at all. *"xdebug.remote_port = 80"* WHY 80? Please check how Xdebug works first and what that value is for. https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#communication

Answer (score 1):

Your setup may differ slightly (because I'm using this inside Laradock - so it has that Laravel flavour) but I believe the configs should helpful to you.

Some of these setting may be superfluous, but they're pulled from a number of tutorials and are working very well on my Localhost setup.

**php.ini**

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal  // important if using Mac
xdebug.remote_port=9000                  // important for connection to occur
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.max_nesting_level=250
xdebug.remote_log=/var/www/xdebug_log/xdebug_docker.log  // for debugging Xdebug!

xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "log": true,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/app": "${workspaceFolder}/app"  // repoint this
            },
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_data": 65535,
                "show_hidden": 1,
                "max_children": 100,
                "max_depth": 5
            }
        }
    ]
}
```